# Get Phone ISD Country code given ISO2 Country code using google libPhone

Tags: java

I am using Google's libPhoneNumber.

I have a ISO2 country code (say: JM :: Jamaica)

I wanted to get the ISD Country code for this country.

I am doing it as follows:

```
PhoneNumberUtil pnu = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
int isd_cc = pnu.getCountryCodeForRegion("JM");
```

But it seems to return value : **1**

As per wikipedia or countrycode.org the expected value seems to be **1-876**

Is this a bug in the libPhoneNumber library. Also, it would be great if someone can suggest a better way to get the ISD Country code.